# Update field of embedded documents on multiple Mongoid documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have following two Mongoid documents:

```
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :pages
end

class Page
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :book
  field :reviewer, type: String
  field :done, type: Boolean
end
```

And I created two `Book` documents with four `Page` documents embedded:

```
reviewers = %w(Alice Bob Charlie)

2.times do
  book = Book.new
  4.times do
    reviewer = reviewers.sample
    book.pages << Page.new(reviewer: reviewer, done: false)
  end
  book.save
end
```

Note that the reviewer is chosen from `reviewers` randomly.

I want to set `done` field to `true` for all `Page` documents reviewed by 'Alice' at a time. How can I do it?

I wrote following code:

```
Book.where('pages.reviewer' => 'Alice').set('pages.$.done' => true)
```

This update only one `Page` document for each `Book` document even if several pages are reviewed by 'Alice'.

I use mongoid 4.0.0.alpha1.

Comment: Thanks everyone for pointing me to a relevant answer. The short answer to my question is "You cannot do that", isn't it?